# Why Postgresql 9.2 word boundary not working!

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

In my postgresql version 9.1 this query is working fine:

```
select id,name from flash_card_set where name ~* '\yACT\y'
```

and matching:
`text ACT txt`,
`ACT tests`,
`tests ACT`
But in my postgresql version 9.2 it is not matching any of them.Am I missing something!

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details. Platform/OS/version, how you upgraded to 9.2, etc.

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect you have `standard_conforming_strings` set to OFF on the 9.1 instance (meaning it was changed explicitly, since the default is ON since 9.1), and the opposite in 9.2.

Demo:

```
test=> select version();
                                                   version                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

 test=> show standard_conforming_strings ;
 standard_conforming_strings 
-----------------------------
 on
(1 row)

test=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('text ACT txt'), ('ACT tests'), ('tests ACT'))
test-> SELECT v FROM x WHERE v ~* '\yACT\y';
      v       
--------------
 text ACT txt
 ACT tests
 tests ACT
(3 rows)
```

Now with it to OFF:

```
test=> set standard_conforming_strings=off;
SET

test=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('text ACT txt'), ('ACT tests'), ('tests ACT'))
SELECT v FROM x WHERE v ~* '\yACT\y';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 2: SELECT v FROM x WHERE v ~* '\yACT\y';
                                   ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
 v 
---
(0 rows)
```

You'd need also to set `escape_string_warning` to OFF to mute the warning message and get a final result that plausibly matches your question:

```
test=> set escape_string_warning to off;
SET
test=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('text ACT txt'), ('ACT tests'), ('tests ACT'))
SELECT v FROM x WHERE v ~* '\yACT\y';
 v 
---
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Good spot Daniel. I would have expected that the GIANT WARNING MESSAGES @MD.MohiuddinAhmed would've got about this on 9.1 should have been a hint, but i guess they chose to suppress and ignore them. Hmm, I guess we had those warnings for a reason after all.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
regress=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('text ACT txt'), ('ACT tests'), ('tests ACT'))
regress-> SELECT v FROM x WHERE v ~* '\yACT\y';
      v       
--------------
 text ACT txt
 ACT tests
 tests ACT
(3 rows)
```

on:

```
regress=> SELECT version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

so you should probably provide more details.

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit"

Comment: It's giving me 0 rows